# Hinge parts between instruction steps in Studio 2

Tags: bricklink-studio

LEGO instructions sometimes hinge out bricks between two steps, as shown in this example taken from an instruction randomly:

Step 25: [image: Extract from step 25 from set 41328]

Step 26: [image: Extract from step 26 from set 41328]

Is it possible to do something similar in Studio 2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The only workaround I can imagine is creating the building instructions on BL Studio until the step with the hinge. Then export as PDF. Do the hinge(s) and go ahead with the instructions. At last merge the PDF files.